# How can I get the tuesday of the week n in a year

Tags: java, localdate

How can I get the friday of the 34th week of the year? Not just the friday. Any day, I want to get the current week of the year, and in this week I want the friday. Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Calendar` class:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setWeekDate(2020, 34, Calendar.FRIDAY);
```

Then you can access the `Date` object for this day like this:

```
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Which will print (for me): `Fri Aug 21 15:45:22 CEST 2020`.
Or you can even access the individual calendar fields like so:

```
System.out.println(
    "YEAR: " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "\n" +
    "MONTH: " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "\n" +
    "DAY: " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

This will print:

```
YEAR: 2020
MONTH: 21
DAY: 7
```

Just don't make the mistake to try to achieve things like this purely with the help of `Date`.

Comment: Oh, look! A downvote without a comment! How nice! Does this somehow _not_ answer the question?

Comment: Not sure why, but I think the downvote is because you are referring to old classes, instead of showing the newer Date/Time api's

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me!
btw, that downvote isnt from me..

Comment: What's wrong with "old" classes if they can produce such a concise solution?